# Bucle finaliza antes de recorrer todas las lineas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy recorriendo un diccionario pero cuando este lee la linea

> 'noProxy'  : ''})

sale del for volviendo a la linea

> config = configparser.ConfigParser()

y vuelve a comenzar todo nuevamente, no llegando a leer el total del código dentro del bucle:

```
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    # disable images to speed up the page loading
    prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
```

Este es el código:

```
import configparser
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

class Proxy:

def __init__(self):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(testdir + '\config.ini')
    proxy = config["Proxy"]

    for pais, ip in proxy.items():

        proxy_ = Proxy({'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL,'httpProxy': {ip},'ftpProxy' : {ip},'sslProxy' : {ip},'noProxy'  : ''})
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

        prefs = {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2}
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

        capabilities = dict(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
        proxy_.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)
```

Estos son los datos que estan dentro del archivo config.ini

```
[Proxy]
Brasil: 186.233.104.25:8080
Chile: 190.82.76.58:32570
Ecuador: 186.3.228.98:8080
```

Comment: Lo dudo, pero no será que aqui te falta un corchete? 'noProxy' : {''})

Comment: Fuera del for funciona correctamente por eso no comprendo que sucede

Comment: Por cierto, reasignar un nuevo valor a la variable `proxy` (diccionario sobre el que itera el `for`) en `proxy = Proxy({...})` puede traer algunos problemas (no en el funcionamiento del propio for). Considera cambiar el nombre de dicha variable interna, aunque solo sea por legibilidad.

Comment: Lo tengo tal cual esta arriba, yo tampoco entiendo porque sale del bucle en esa linea y vuelve a configparser.ConfigParser()

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que sale en esa línea exactamente?¿Has colocado un `print(pais)` por ejemplo después de  `proxy.add_to_capabilities(capabilities)`, al mismo nivel a ver si imprime algo?

Comment: Sisi, tambien agrege un breekpoint en esa linea y es donde hace el salto hacia configparser.... saliendo totalmente del bucle

Comment: Sebastian es que tal como tienes el código de ese módulo (he corregido la identación, comprueba que es correcto) es imposible que salte hacia atrás (a no ser que sea cosa del IDE y el breakpoint, yo lo quitaría y haría el print que te comento si no lo has hecho).. Por las dudas, he probado tu código y no tiene problema alguno.

Comment: La única forma de que un for-in como el tuyo salga antes de iterar completamente sobre el diccionario (sin break o terminando la ejecución del script) es mediante una excepción (que no dices tener). Además, jamás volvería a ejecutar la primera línea del script, aún rompiendo el ciclo se continúa con las líneas que le siguen. Para que "salte" a dónde dices no estamos dejando algo importante atrás, porque parece que existiera un `goto` a lo C invisible... :).

Comment: Me lo hace siempre, ya probe con dos ide, me esta volviendo loco este error

Comment: Ejecutas el script que hay arriba (**exactamente como está**, sin estar englobado en una clase o cualquier otra estructura) directamente o lo importas y lo ejecutas desde otro módulo? ¿Que pasa si ejecutas el script desde la terminal directamente? Tiene que haber algo más, porque lo que cuentas va en contra del diseño mismo del lenguaje... :(

Comment: Si dentro de una clase, lo agrege completo no hay mas je, ahora llega a proxy_ y vuelve al for, ya no sale del mismo, pero siempre itinera sobre el mismo valor en este caso el primero encontrado 'Brasil' y sigue sin terminar de recorrer todo lo que se encuentra dentro del bucle

Comment: Tienes un bucle de recursión infinita, ya que dentro del constructor de `Proxy`, instancias un objeto de tipo `Proxy()`, lo que vuelve a llamar al mismo constructor.

Comment: Tal como comenta abulafia, tienes un bucle infinito. La causa es que **llamas a tu clase (`Proxy`) igual que a la clase  que importas de `selenium.webdriver.common.proxy`**, esto hace que cuando dentro del constructor haces `proxy_ = Proxy({...})` estás instanciando a tu propia clase `Proxy` dentro de su propio inicializador y así infinitamente, no instancias a la clase de selenium como debería ser. **Cambia el nombre de tu clase**, o el del import `from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy as SProxy`por ejemplo o importa de otra forma para evitar el solapamiento.